# How to write absolute value and square root in one equation?(runge kutta)

Tags: differential-equations

I got some problem when I run my program. It  hangs when I run it.
This is my coding for runge kutta Geometric mean(RKGM).

```
f[x_, y_] := y*x^2 - 1.2*y;
x0 = 0; y0 = 1;
xf = 2;
n = 5;
x = x0; y = y0;
Do[k1 = f[x, y];
 k2 = f[x + h/2, y + h*k1/2];
 k3 = f[x + h/2, y + (h*(-k1 + 9*k2)/16)];
 k4 = f[x + h, y + (h*(-3*k1 + 5*k2 + 22*k3)/24)];
 y = y + (h*(sqrt[abs[k1*k2]] + sqrt[abs[k2*k3]] + sqrt[abs[k3*k4]])/
      3);
 x = x + h;
 Print[x, " ", y],
 {i, 1, n}]
```

Can someone help me? Please. Thank you.

Comment: Use `Sqrt` and `Abs` (not  `sqrt` and `abs`).

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Answer (score 1):

The Formula

> [image]

***Implementation***

```
rungeKuttaOrderFour[{xn_, yn_}, step_, func_] :=
 Module[{K1, K2, K3, K4},
  K1 = func[xn, yn];
  K2 = func[xn + 1/2 step, yn + 1/2 step K1];
  K3 = func[xn + 1/2 step, yn + 1/2 step K2];
  K4 = func[xn + step, yn + step K3];
  {xn + step, yn + 1./6 step (K1 + 2 K2 + 2 K3 + K4)}
]
```

***Testing***

```
f[x_, y_] := y*x^2 - 1.2*y;
NestList[
 rungeKuttaOrderFour[#, .1, f] &, {0, 1}, 10] // TableForm
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{cc}
>  0 & 1 \\
>  0.1 & 0.887216 \\
>  0.2 & 0.788729 \\
>  0.3 & 0.703984 \\
>  0.4 & 0.632126 \\
>  0.5 & 0.572162 \\
>  0.6 & 0.523091 \\
>  0.7 & 0.484002 \\
>  0.8 & 0.454148 \\
>  0.9 & 0.433008 \\
>  1. & 0.420351 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

Comment: This is the classical RK, not the "geometric mean" variant that OP is interested in.

Comment: @Guesswhoitis.,OK, thanks a lot for mentioning it. The OP could rewrite his code according to this toy-code.

Answer (score 1):

Just another way:

```
rk[fun_, {x_, y_}, h_] := {x + h, 
  y + FoldList[fun[x + #2, y + #2 #1] &, fun[x, y], {h/2, h/2, h}].{1,
       2, 2, 1} h/6}
```

Testing (as per Shutao Tang):

```
g[x_, y_] := y x^2 - 1.2 y
Grid[Prepend[
Thread[Prepend[Transpose[NestList[rk[g, #, 0.1] &, {0, 1}, 10]], 
Range[0, 10]]], {"n", "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(x\), \(n\)]\)", 
"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(y\), \(n\)]\)"}]]
```

[image]